# React transition group - reload same component but swap contents after exit

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

So, I've got a `CSSTransitionGroup` around my router `Switch`, which has a route containing the component `CurrentProject` inside it (among a couple others).

The transitions themselves are working fine, as is the switch. However, if the route is changed from one matching `CurrentProject` to another also matching `CurrentProject` (i.e, a different project), the enter/exit transition and new `Project` are loaded around the same time, so you can see the title and content swap over during the transition.

Is there a way for `react-transition-group` to do its 'exit' transition, then wait for the content to load, *then* do its 'enter' transition?

Answer (score 0):

are you putting `location={history.location}` param into the Switch tag? Its necessary for holding the content in the leaving component...

Comment: Hey again Melounek,

I've got the `location` param set to `{this.props.location}`, but get an error if I use `history` - is there a difference?